# Send Parameters from View to API AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

so I have this view page on angular js

```
<p>This is the about Submission Details</p>
<div class="container">

<div class="col-sm-3">
    <label>
        Name:
        <div class="input-group">
        <input id="applicant-name-home-loan" type="text" name="name_value" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" required>
    </div>
  </label>
 </div>

 <div class="col-sm-3">
    <label>
    Email:
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="email" name="email_value" class="form-control" placeholder="email@example.com" required>
    </div>
  </label>
  </div>         

<div class="col-sm-3">
    <label>
    Telephone:
        <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="telephone" class="form-control" placeholder="012 3456 789" required>
      </div>
    </label>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-2">
    <label>
    Nationality:
    <div class="input-group">
        <select class="form-control" name="hnationality_type">
        <option value="" default selected class="placeholder">Please Select</option>
        <option>Malaysian</option>
        <option>Singaporean</option>
        <option>Others</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </label>
</div>

              <div class="col-sm-1">
                <label>
                  Age:
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" name="age" class="form-control custom-age-width" placeholder="30" maxlength="2">
                  </div>
                </label>
              </div>

            <div class="row padding-top-extra">

              <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label>
                  Monthly gross income:
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" name="monthly_income" class="form-control" placeholder="5000" required>
                  </div>
                </label>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label>
                  Other loan amount:
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" name="other_loan_amount" class="form-control" placeholder="0">
                  </div>
                </label>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-2">
                <label>
                  Your location:
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <select class="form-control" name="happlicant_state" required>
                      <option>Please Select</option>
                      <option>Johor</option>
                      <option>Kedah</option>
                      <option>Kelantan</option>
                      <option>Kuala Lumpur</option>
                      <option>Melaka</option>
                      <option>Negeri Sembilan</option>
                      <option>Pahang</option>
                      <option>Penang</option>
                      <option>Perak</option>
                      <option>Perlis</option>
                      <option>Putrajaya</option>
                      <option>Sabah</option>
                      <option>Sarawak</option>
                      <option>Selangor</option>
                      <option>Terengganu</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </label>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-2">
                <label>
                  Property status:
                  <select class="form-control" name="hcompletion_status">
                    <option>Please Select</option>
                    <option>Completed</option>
                    <option>Under Construction</option>
                  </select>  
                </label>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-2">
                <label>
                  Paid boooking:
                  <select class="form-control" name="his_booking_fee_paid" required>
                    <option>Please Select</option>
                    <option>Yes</option>
                    <option>No</option>
                  </select>  
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <p>
                  <input type="checkbox" class="income-confirm-checkbox" name="income-confirm-checkbox" id="income-confirm-checkbox" required>
                  <label for="income-confirm-checkbox" class="income-confirm-checkbox-label">
                    My income is greated than RM24,000 a year. That's at least RM2000 monthly.
                  </label>
                </p>
                <p>By typing your contact information, you agree to our <a href="/terms-of-use">terms &amp; conditions</a>. We respect your <a href="/privacy-policy">privacy</a> and are committed to handle your personal information safely and responsibly.</p>

              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row apply-form-btn-row">
              <button class="btn btn-default btn-application-submit" role="next" ng-click="submit_info('/thank_you')">Submit</button>
              <button class="btn btn-default apply-cancel-btn" role="cancel">Cancel</button>
            </div>
</div>
```

And I have this controller page in AngularJS mortgage.js

```
 angular.module('loanstreetIpadAppApp')
      .controller('Mortgage_LoanCtrl', function ($location, $scope, $http) {
        console.log('LOAD Mortgage_LoanCtrl');

 $scope.submit_info = function() {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/mortgage/submit',
            data: {
                name: params['name_value'],
                email:params['email_value'],
                phone_number: params['telephone'],
            }
        }).success (function(data) {
                console.log('Data stored');
                console.log(data);
        }).error(function(reason) {
                    console.log(reason);
            });
         $location.path(path);
    };

});
```

Ok I want to create a json api with the values from my view page. How do i call the input values and how do i create a json api for this in my controller using AngularJS.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by json API. 
if you want to submit the json data then here is how you do it.

```
$scope.submit_info = function() {
          console.log($scope.info)
          $http({
              method: 'POST',
              url: '/mortgage/submit',
              data: $scope.info
          }).success (function(data) {
              console.log('Data stored');
              console.log(data);
              //redirect only after you recieve response.
              //$location.path(path);
          }).error(function(reason) {
              console.log(reason);
              //redirect only after you recieve response.
              //$location.path(errorPath);
          });
      };
```

go to the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chandings/d90ymw79/) link to see the full code.
Mind you there is no backend so it will go to error function. 
Also you need to add the validations and there are various ways to do it.
the best way as per me is to create your own wrapper input fields each validating itself.

Comment: yes that's exactly what i mean submit the json data Thanks @chandings. ur answer was spot on.

Comment: do u by any clue know how to parse the json api to rails controller? Even after adding the CORS headers i am still getting an error

Comment: I am sorry. I got no clue.